# TikZ miscalculates some intersections, dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, dimensions, intersections

I want to draw some arcs inside a circle: they go from angle (120i+30)/2^j to (120i+90)/2^j for all i,j. I compute them with TikZ as follows:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{fp}\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\def\myarc#1#2{\path[name path=a] ({#1}:1) -- ($({#1}:1)!10cm!270:(0,0)$);
  \path[name path=b] ({#2}:1) -- ($({#2}:1)!10cm!90:(0,0)$);
  \draw[name intersections={of=a and b,by=t}] (t) let \p1 = ($(t)-({#1}:1)$) in
  circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \clip (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \begin{scope}[very thick]\myarc{120}{240}\end{scope}
    \myarc{300}{60}
    \foreach\j/\k in {1/360,2/720,4/1440,8/2880,16/5760,32/11520} { %,64/23040} {
      \foreach\i in {150,330,...,\k} {\myarc{\i/\j}{(\i+60)/\j}};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The result is fine up to j=16, but for the next one (j=32) some of the circles are not correctly placed; and for j=64 TikZ refuses to compile the picture, with a "dimension too large" error.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dimension too large` error appears because you need to use a huge `\k` in your approach. I agree with caverac in that you do not have to compute the intersections, but I disagree with the computation of the centers of the circles. In your code, these are at the intersections (which BTW could easier be obtained with `tangent cs:`). In principle you do not have to draw the full circles, but only arcs, but because of the way Ti*k*Z treats angles that overshoot 360 degrees I was unable to make this work. **UPDATE** with a big thanks to grok: changed the ordering of how to divide by `2^\k`.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\DrawArc}[3][]{ % from angle #2-#3 to #2+#3
  \draw[#1] ({#2}:{sec(#3)}) circle ({tan(#3)});
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \draw[very thin] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \clip (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \DrawArc[thick]{180}{60}
  \foreach\k in {0,...,7} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{2*2^\k}
    \foreach\i in {1,...,\j} {\DrawArc{180/2^\k*\i}{30/2^\k}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, your method of computing the centers (with 1/cos and tan) is much better than mine. However, the "overflow" problem persists when k=6.

The solution, so it seems, is to compute (180/2^\k*\i-30/2^k) rather than (180*\i-30)/2^\k which causes an overflow.

Comment: Here is the "perfect" solution. Can you change it so I can select your answer? By the way, how to you display the result of TeX code in a post? Thanks again!

\newcommand{\DrawArc}[3][]{ % from angle #2-#3 to #2+#3
  \draw[#1] ({#2}:{sec(#3)}) circle ({tan(#3)});
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \clip (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \DrawArc[thick]{180}{60}
  \foreach\k in {0,...,6} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{2*2^\k}
    \foreach\i in {1,...,\j} {\DrawArc{180/2^\k*\i}{30/2^\k}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @grok I agree. You can even improve on that one.

Comment: @grok What do you mean by "results". I usually just take a screenshot and put it into the answer using the `insert picture` icon on the top bar of the typing area.

Comment: Ah, OK. I now see how to edit your post, I'll do it.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid drawing the arcs, if you just calculate the centers of the circles directly and then just clip them

[image]

And this is the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 3]
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \clip (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \foreach \i in {1,...,128} {
    \foreach \j in {1,...,32} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{\fpeval{(120 * \i + 60) / 2^\j}}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dtheta}{\fpeval{60 / 2^\j}}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{0.5 * sqrt(2 - 2 * cos(\dtheta))}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{cos(\theta)} 
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{sin(\theta)}
      \draw[] (\x, \y) circle (\r);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but I *do* compute the centers of the arcs! The next answer does compute the centers more efficiently.

Comment: @grok Great! I'm glad you found the answer you're looking for